# How do I prove that $f(n)=o(g(n))$ if and only if $g(n)=\omega(f(n))$

Tags: notation, asymptotics

I don't know how can I prove this:

prove that $f(n)=o(g(n))$ if and only if $g(n)=\omega(f(n))$

Comment: what do the symbols $o$ and $\omega$ mean for you?

Comment: use the definition of $o$ and $\omega$. The proof is immediate and trivial